# URL rewriting problem during browser back

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am following the scottgu's tutorial and it's working fine except when I press the browser back button.

WHen I go back to the previous page, it does not display data for that page, I cannot debug the page also using breakpoint is VS, when I go back and refresh the page, the data is shown.

How to rectify this ?

tutorial:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

I am using Approach 2: Using an HttpModule to Perform URL Rewriting

EDIT: It's working fine in Chrome.
I show "data does not exist" when the data does not exist.I removed that from my webpage and ran that page in IE 9, but it funny that IE still displays "data does not exist".  I cleared the browser history also. Still did not work.

EDIT: I uninstalled IE 9 to IE 8 and it works perfectly.

Moderators: Please see what can be done to this question(delete ?) as there is no answer possible to this question.

Comment: A link to the tutorial you're referring to would be handy, as there's not enough to work with here.

Comment: If you press the back-button on the browser, I believe there is no communication with the server. Doesn't the browser just get the page from it's cache? Perhaps you are using Ajax to change things in the page that don't end up in cache?

Comment: @Robb: I provided the link, @Bazzz I am not using Ajax.

Comment: looks like this is the problem of the buggy internet explorer. Will provide an update when I am sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to IE 9

I rolled back to IE 8 and it worked smooth.